# Can't disable Sirikit in an app

Tags: ios, sirikit

I added SiriKit to a version of my, but then decided to remove it.  The problem is that Siri still offers to use my app when I ask it to do the function that app used to do.  I have deleted and re-installed the app (with no Siri support), but it still wants to use my app when I speak the keywords that another version of the app once supported.  I restarted the iPhone, but it still remember.  I also disabled Siri in the settings for this app; still remembers.

Is this an iOS 11 bug?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:
You need to go back to the version of the app that supported SiriKit and in the info.plist for the Intent extension and in the IntentsSupported remove the intent that your app previously supported and replace it with some other intent.

Seems like an iOS bug.  Disabling Siri for the app in the Settings should have disabled Siri from using the app for the intent.